# tess-two can't find libpng.so

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

I have followed building instructions for tess-two on
[Github](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#build)

I build tess-two using NDK successfully and imported the library
I am trying to run the test application provided on the same repository but whenever the application starts it gives the following exception:
That  error is caused once `new TessBaseAPI();` is called.

```
dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-2/liblept.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libpng.so" needed by "liblept.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libpng.so" not found
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using precompiled versions of liblept.so and libtess.so? Alongside those files in the tess-two libs folder there should be a file named libpng.so.

Comment: @rmtheis  I'm not sure since when tess-two depends on libpng (we're using it without it), but for me it seems like `System.loadLibrary("png")` call is missing in `TessBaseAPI`. Maybe you should try that before `new TessBaseAPI()`

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev You're right, it should be loaded explicitly using `System.loadLibrary`. This seems to be an issue only on some 4.x versions of Android. Would you please add that suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have followed suggestion of Dmitry Zaitsev & thannks to him , solved my problem also .

Please update your TessBaseAPI.java from tess-two library project as below :

```
   static {
        System.loadLibrary("png");
        System.loadLibrary("lept");
        System.loadLibrary("tess");

        nativeClassInit();
     }
```

Build tess-two project after updating these file . In my case I have build it using eclipse.
Hope it should solve your problem as well.

Comment: Or better, make a pull request to original tess-two project :)

Comment: I've made this [change](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/commit/ab1b1c81f4aea21c300736a7df186673a1bcd480) to the tess-two code. All versions of Android should now be able to see libpng. You can do a `git pull` in your tess-two directory to bring in the changes. No need to re-run your ndk-build.

Comment: This solved my problem. Had to include System.loadLibrary("jpgt") also.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `System.loadLibrary("png")` call is missing in `TessBaseAPI`, therefore library can't be found.

Try to call `System.loadLibrary("png")` **before** calling `new TessBaseAPI()`. Typically this is done in `static` initialization block, like so:

```
public class MyClass {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("png");
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        new TessBaseAPI();
    }
}
```