# libs folder in tess-two and eyes-two are empty

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess-two

So I successfully built tess-two using the following commands

```
git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess
cd tess
cd tess-two
ndk-build -path '~/Desktop/OCR/tess/eyes-two/jni'
android update project --target 6--path .
ant release
```

The reason Why I had to use ndk-build -path /path/to/jni/ vs. ndk-build is because I got the error:

> make: /Users/Bhavik/build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or directory
>   make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/Bhavik/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop.

This is the same as [NDK build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938098/ndk-build-error)

I also had to add --target 6 (is this is a problem)?

I successfully build it : BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 3 seconds

However when I import it into my project and run it, I run into this problem:
[tess-two can't find libpng.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833308/tess-two-cant-find-libpng-so)

I checked my libs folder at tess/tess-two/libs/ and its completely empty. Can someone please help me with whats happening here?
I am aware that this may be a duplicate but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my fault. It was because my ndk was placed in a folder that had a space thus when trying to run ndk-build it would give me an error. I reran and saw it compile the libraries.

I got it working, now to tackle the worst accuracy in the world.